# Clipping a Pandas dataframe to a shapefile using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, clip, arcmap

I have a Pandas dataframe containing Latitude and Longitude data for an abundance of points, and I would like to clip them to a shapefile; ie: everything outside the boundaries of the shapefile is dropped.

Is there a way to achieve this within a Python package such as MatPlotLib?

I have searched on Google, but 'clipping' seems to refer to data being cut off by map legends/axis rather than what I'm describing.

This image displays what I'm after - I did this in ArcMap but need to automate the process. The grey points represent the entire dataframe, while red points are 'clipped' to the green shapefile below.

[image: Clipped points (Red)]

Here is the code I'm running to over-lay the points in case it is of any use:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(1, figsize=(12, 12))
ax.plot(Easting,Northing, 'bo', markersize=5)
IMD.plot(column='imd_score', colormap='Blues', linewidth=0.1, axes=ax)
locs, labels = plt.xticks()
plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)
plt.axis('equal')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try [geopandas](http://geopandas.org/). It's a very good library that works basically with pandas dataframes, but geolocalized, i.e. containing a column of Geometry. You can import export shapefiles directly within it, and finally do something like [Intersection](http://geopandas.org/user.html#geodataframe).